# Idiomatic way to change data before serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

In a project I'm currently working on, suppose I have a model called Company and an attribute of that is name. Now imagine that this model has a one-to-many relationship with a model called User. That is, Company has_many Users. The User model has a foreign key 'company_id' to keep track of what it belongs to.

Now imagine that I want to send this User record over to the front-end (Ember + Ember-data) for some reason, and I would want to convert the company_id to the company name. Is there an idiomatic way for doing this other than

```
render json: {Company.find(user.company_id), ...}
```

that wouldn't require typing out all the attributes?

Many thanks in advance,

Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gem 'active_model_serializers'

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Its good.